# Prove optimality of the output of the algorithm

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

> **Problem:** Given $c \in \mathbb { R } _ { + } ^ { n } , a \in \mathbb { R } _ { + } ^ { n }$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb { R } _ { + } ,$ design an algorithm which, in $O ( n \log n )$ operations, computes the optimal solution $x ^ { * }$ to the following linear program :
>
> $$\begin{array} { c l } { \max } & { c ^ { T } x } \\ { \text { s.t. } } & { a ^ { T } x \leq \gamma } \\ { } & { 0 \leq x _ { i } \leq 1 , \quad \forall i \in [ n ] } \end{array}$$
>
> You may assume that a set of $n$ real numbers can be sorted in time $O ( n \log n )$ and that each arithmetic operation takes constant time.

Thanks to @lonzaleggiera on [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208200/find-an-optimal-solution-to-a-linear-program-in-o-n-log-n) I managed to write an algorithm in $O ( n \log n )$ time that compute an optimal solution to my LP. I am now trying to prove optimality. Here you can find his answer:

> You sort the $c _ { i } / a _ { i }$ from highest to lowest: $c _ { i _ { 1 } } / a _ { i _ { 1 } } , c _ { i _ { 2 } } / a _ { i _ { 2 } } , \ldots , c _ { i _ { n } } / a _ { i _ { n } } ,$ and find the largest value of $k$ for which $\sum _ { j = 1 } ^ { k } a _ { i _ { j } } \leq \gamma ,$ then set $x _ { i _ { j } } = 1$ for $j = 1,2 , \ldots , k ,$ and $$x _ { i _ { k + 1 } } = \left( \gamma - \sum _ { j = 1 } ^ { k } a _ { i _ { j } } x _ { i _ { j } } \right) / a _ { i _ { k + 1 } }$$

**My attempt**: Suppose for a contradiction $\exists y \in \mathbb { R }^ { n }$ such that $c^T x < c^T y$, with $x$ the output of our algorithm.

$\Rightarrow \exists j_0 \in \text{{$1,...,n$}}$ s.t  $c_{i_{j_0}}x_{i_{j_0}} < c_{i_{j_0}}y_{i_{j_0}} $

$\Rightarrow x_{i_{j_0}} < y_{i_{j_0}} $ since $c_{i_{j_0}} \neq 0$

We can now study 3 cases :

1. If $j_0 \in \text{{$1,...,k$}}$: then  $x_{j_0} = 1 < y_{j_0}$ since $0\leq y_i \leq 1$ by our constraints. Contradiction
2. If $j_0 = k +1$: then $x_{j_0} = x_{k+1} < y_{k+1}$

   $\Rightarrow \frac{\gamma - s}{a_{i_{k+1}}} < y_{k+1}$

   $\Rightarrow \gamma < s + a_{i_{k+1}}y_{k+1} = \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} a_{i_j}y_j \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i_j}y_j$

   $\Rightarrow \gamma < a^T t$ Contradiction
3. If $j_0 \in \text{{$k+2,...,n$}}$ and here I'm lost.

What would be your strategy to solve this last case? The issue is that I don't have much information on my optimal solution $y$ and I don't know where the contradiction would rise off.

Answer (score 2):

I would prove this by demonstrating a solution to the dual linear program that has the same objective value as the primal solution you obtained.
Let me know if you need more of a hint.